# Is there a way to email SSRS execution reports

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have an SSIS package that runs daily, and we are now starting to add error handling into it.

However, I was wondering that if instead of adding email tasks into SSIS to notify us of errors, we could simply have the execution report of the job sent to us via email, preferably only if the job failed. Is this possible?

EDIT: Actually it would be really useful if I could email the report if the Job succeeded but there has been a warning (e.g. no files found to process at a given step). Is that possible, or would I have to add such tasks in the SSIS package itself?

Comment: If the SSIS package runs via a Sql agent job why not send an email notification when the Sql job reports an error

Comment: @davey I can see how SQL can notify an operator if there is an error in the execution of the job. But is there a way to email if there has been a warning? Or do I have to edit the SSIS in Visual Studio and add a task to email if files aren't found? I would prefer to simply send me the report onWarning if possible.

Comment: not sure you can do it via SQL job on a warning just on an error. What you could do is throw an error in SSIS when it finds no files rather then a warning.